Macro is not working when I clicked the button
I have my vba code in which the button (from control) i have created in Sheet3 will simply check if value from cell C2 and cell G2 in Sheet1 are the same, then it will copy the value from cell G2 to cell J2 in Sheet2 blank row. And it will run in loop for the rest of cells to be validation in Sheet1. It is working once, however, now that I run it again, it is not working or doing anything. There is also no error showing, the reason why I also don't know what is wrong with my vba code. I hope you could help me figure what's wrong is happening.
Below is my vba codes:
    Sub CopyCopyPasteRowsToSheet2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Find the last row in Sheet2
    lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Check conditions for each row in Sheet1 and copy & paste accordingly
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, "G").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Range("G2:J2").Copy ws2.Cells(lastRow, "A")
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        
        If ws1.Cells(i, "K").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Range("K2:N2").Copy ws2.Cells(lastRow, "A")
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        
        If ws1.Cells(i, "O").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Range("O2:R2").Copy ws2.Cells(lastRow, "A")
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        
        If ws1.Cells(i, "S").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Range("S2:V2").Copy ws2.Cells(lastRow, "A")
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
        
        If ws1.Cells(i, "W").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Range("W2:Z2").Copy ws2.Cells(lastRow, "A")
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Put a msgbox somewhere near the top, to see what it's doing. You could show the values of the variables in the message, to help decipher. Or, you could put some breakpoints in to see if the code is getting run. You may also want to clear down your variable (set them to 0/null) before you end sub.

Will try this. Thanks!

Your code differs from your description. If you have i=2 then Cells(i, "G") refers to G2, but Rows(i).Range("G2:J2") refers to G3:J3. Maybe it should be: Rows(i).Range("G1:J1") ?

I have a header in my columns the reason why the i=2 so that it will start to check the values on cell 2. Hope that helps. thanks!

You say "it is not working or doing anything".. are you sure it's not just overwriting the output created last time? If column A (the column you're using to detect lastrow) is empty, it will start writing the output from the same place as last time.
